# Stored procedure that accepts multiple parameters

Tags: php, stored-procedures

It's my first time working with stored procedures.

The previous developer already had a stored procedure in place that works, but it only accepts 1 parameter.

I am using PHP to pass the parameters:

```
 <?php
   $containers = $_POST['cntnum'];

   $shortened = array();
   foreach($containers as $short)
   {
     $shortened[] = substr($short, 0, 10);
   }
   $sans_check = preg_replace('/\n$/','',preg_replace('/^\n/','',preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/',"\n",$shortened)));
   $sans = "'" . implode("', '", $sans_check) ."'";

   // At this point, $sans looks like this: 'value1', 'value2', 'value3'... 

   // now I send $sans to the stored procedure
   $thecall = mysqli_query($dbc, "CALL SP_ContSearch_TEST($sans)");
 ?>
```

I can send 1 value with no problem.  I get back the data.  But when there are more than 1, I get the following error:

```
Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE table.storeprocedure; expected 1, got 3
```

Here is what the stored procedure looks like (shortened for time):

```
Begin
  DECLARE sans_check varchar(100);  // adjusted from 10, but same error message
  SET sans_check = SUBSTR(cont,1,10);
  SELECT
    `inventory`
    ,delivery_date
    ,pool
  FROM 
    inventory
  WHERE
    CONTAINER_CHECK IN (cont);
  END
```

The parameter cont is varchar(11) // not sure if that means anything

This is my first attempting a stored procedure call, and I can return data for one value.  I need to return data for multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is absolutely right. You are sending 3 parameters to a stored procedure which takes only one.

What you've done is you have modified the stored procedure which takes a single string such that it still expects a single string.

You should modify the definition of the stored procedure to take 3 parameters (that part is missing in your question)

Here is an example of a stored procedure declaration with 3 parameters:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ContSearch_TEST
    (IN sans1 CHAR(10),
     IN sans2 CHAR(10),
     IN sans3 CHAR(10)
     -- add as many other parameters here as you need
    )
 BEGIN
     -- your stored proc logic here.. can use sans1, sans2, and sans3
 END
```

You should also change your code to use parameterized queries instead of the way you're doing right now. See: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php or http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: How would I go about modifying the definition of the stored procedure?  It should be able to accept a max of 10 parameters.

Comment: @JohnBeasley please see the updated answer for a generic definition with 3 parameters. You should be able to extrapolate to more params. Also, what RDBMS are you using? The syntax might be slightly different in different databases

Comment: Don't forget to DROP the existing procedure in you declaration otherwise you'll get an exception.

Comment: If you really need a variable number of arguments you can always look at creating a UDF ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/udf-arguments.html however you're then aswell just writing a PHP function... also is the Stored Proc really needed?

Comment: Good news and bad news.  I recreated the stored procedure as you indicated above, and I can now return data for 10 different values.  However...10 values MUST be submitted.  The user can enter up to 10, but may enter less.  Therefore, I'm kind of back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Brian - Well, I'm using the stored procedure because from what I've read, being that this site will be outfacing, it's safer.  At least, that's what I've read.

Comment: @JohnBeasley unfortunately that's how stored procs work. In general stored procs are a good idea but there are some use cases where that's not true. In your case if you know for sure that there can only be up to 10 parameters, you can code it with 10 and in PHP always submit 10, with empty values for the ones that are missing. In the stored proc, code your logic to ignore missing ones. But if you need a variable number of args that is truly arbitrary then stored procs are not the way to go.

Comment: @JohnBeasley just make sure to definitely use parameterized prepared statements regardless of what you end up using (stored procedures or direct queries)

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I will take your suggestions and make it work.  Accepting your answer.