# Check if array has 10 elements if not create blank elements

Tags: php, arrays, stored-procedures

The array is expecting 10 elements (for a stored procedure, which is expecting 10 values).

The user may submit less than 10.  In that event, the array should automatically create blank elements for anything remaining.

The variable initially comes over via post like this:

```
<?php
  $containers = $_POST['cntnum']; // could be equal or less than 10, no more
  $count = count($containers);
  $remainder = 10 - $count;

  // trying to loop and set remaining elements to ''
  for($i = 0; $i < $remainder; $i++)
  {
    // this where I'm lost
  }
?>
```

This is how the variable should look when I send it to the stored procedure:

```
 $sans = 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '';
```

I am trying to use a for loop to set the remaining array elements to ''.

Maybe I don't need the for loop.  Maybe there's another way.  I am open to suggestions.

How can I achieve this?

Note:  I am trying to complete my previous questions here:  [stored procedure that accepts multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241326/stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-parameters)

Comment: In your loop do `$containers[] = "";` This will set the next array value to blank basically.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - Appears your code worked.  Someone provided the same answer below.  If you create one, I'll mark yours as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set an empty value for the array key.

```
$containers = $_POST['cntnum']; // could be equal or less than 10, no more
$count      = count($containers);
$remainder  = 10 - $count;
// trying to loop and set remaining elements to ''
for ($i = 0; $i < $remainder; $i++) {
    //if you don't specify a key, it uses the next available key.
    $containers[] = "";
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to get rid of your loop, use [array_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php).

Using array_pad:

```
$containers = array_pad($containers, 10, '');
```

Comment: Thank you, sir.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JohnBeasley No problem ^.^. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

A generalised answer, given an array `$values` with less than 10 values and you don't want to preserve keys/indexes, you can use `array_fill()` to create an array of a specific size filled with placeholder values, and "merge" this with your `$values` using `array_replace()`; e.g:

```
<?php

$values = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
$merged = array_replace(array_fill(0, 10, ''), $values);

print_r($merged);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => baz
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
)
```

Reference

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_fill()` to fill the remaining indexes with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new "blank" item to the array like this:

```
$containers[] = '';
```

So if you put this into your for-loop, it will add the specified amount of blank items to the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [`array_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) is designed for:

```
<?php

$sans = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'];
$padded = array_pad($sans, 10, '');

print_r($padded);
```

=

```
Array
(
    [0] => value1
    [1] => value2
    [2] => value3
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
)
```